# Display cells from array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

So I've written a code that creates my cell array. I can display the array, but I'm getting a little lost on how to display only the cell's with something in it. I have 44 cells, but only 4 of them have anything in them. Here is what I have so far

```
hashtags = regexpi(z,'\<(#)[a-z0-9_]*\>','match');
celldisp(hashtags)
```

This displays the entire array, and all I need is the four cells that have something in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if each cell is empty using `cellfun`, and use that as logical index:

```
celldisp(hashtags(~cellfun('isempty',hashtags)))
```